# Unity3d show status bar

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I using Unity3d 5.4, i am building an app for Android 4.4+

I tried to show the status bar with

```
Screen.fullscreen = false;
```

however only the navigation bar is shown

Comment: http://zehfernando.com/2015/unity-tidbits-changing-the-visibility-of-androids-navigation-and-status-bars-and-implementing-immersive-mode/

Answer (score 1):

It seems that since Unity 5.3 the "hide status bar" option is not anymore available.

However, after a quick search, solutions exist, [here is a gitHub project](https://github.com/Over17/UnityShowAndroidStatusBar) who seems to solve your problem.

Original post with more informations about this and different solutions discussed [here.](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/status-bar-always-hidden-on-android.362779/)

Comment: Before posting here i actually tried this and it does not work

Comment: so please details your post with what you actually tried that we have a better understanding because that was the most likely answer.

Comment: Great! This one actually worked! Tried on Unity 2017.3 Just read instructions how to implement. Very easy and convenient

Comment: the post you mentioned have some codes which actually worked finally.